# Retain renderCell state after paginating data in DataGrid

Tags: material-ui

Material UI DataGrid Pagination is resetting the values/states of the renderCell componenet.

For example in the following demo, whenever I turn a switch on and move to the second page, that switch resets to initial value when I come back to that page. any idea how to solve this issue ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-material-demo-forked-ygrpw6?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, you need to set the state in the outer component where the data table is being rendered. You can then pass the prop of each switch to the controlled switch.

In the outer component `DataGridDemo()`, the state will be an object of all the rows which are checked.

Your renderCell function will be like:

`renderCell: (e) => <ControlledSwitch checked={checked} setChecked={prev => ({...prev, x: true})} />`
where x signifies the Id of the row that you can fetch from the renderCell prop (e)

And your `ControlledSwitch` function will be like:

```js
export default function ControlledSwitch({checked, setChecked}) {
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <Switch
      checked={checked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work too, can you provide a sandbox demo?